# Need help to resolve issue with Anaconda Python 2.7 x32

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, pythoncom

I've installed Anakonda Python 2.7 x32 package and now can't use native `pythoncom`-library.

Full list of installed 3rd party libraries:

> - PySide
> - ftputil
> - ruamel.yaml/PyYAML
> - PyPDF
> - simplejson
> - PyInstaller
> - sqlparse
> - Padding
> - wmi

Error details here:

```
File "X:\app\src\utils\hardware_info.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pythoncom
  File "C:\Anaconda32\lib\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pywintypes
  File "C:\Anaconda32\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 124, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Anaconda32\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 98, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    raise ImportError("No system module '%s' (%s)" % (modname, filename))
ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes27.dll)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution at this site - http://sourceforge.net/p/pywin32/bugs/685/